# Modify the display of mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Hi i have a mysql table like this:

| TagName | DateTime | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'SGHAST_0001_Temp' | '2022-06-03 15:53:18.2400000' | '7.0' |
| 'SGHAST_0001_HUMIDITY' | '2022-06-03 15:53:18.2400000' | '80.0' |
| 'SGHAST_0002_Temp' | '2022-06-03 15:53:18.2400000' | '17.0' |
| 'SGHAST_0002_HUMIDITY' | '2022-06-03 15:53:18.2400000' | '50.0' |

How to make the table into one row(s) like below here?

| TagName | Temperature | Humidity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SGHAST.0001 | '7.0' | '80.0' |
| SGHAST.0002 | '17.0' | '50.0' |

Can I please also have the lines of code to change to this instead of just a suggestion? because I am new to MySQL. But still any help is appreciated!

My code so far:

```
SELECT DateTime, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN skynet_msa.testingintern.TagName LIKE 'Temp%' 
                THEN value 
                ELSE 0 END) as Temperature,
       SUM(CASE WHEN skynet_msa.testingintern.TagName LIKE 'HUMIDITY%' 
                THEN value 
                ELSE 0 END) as Humidity,
FROM skynet_msa.testingintern
GROUP BY DateTime 
LIMIT 0, 50000;
```

Comment: If you want to learn about MySQL, you should first attempt to solve the problem yourself, otherwise you won't move from your *new to MySQL* condition.

Comment: @lemon i attempted to code but failed to do so that's why i come here to ask for help

Comment: Please share it, maybe you already did a great query that just needs some quick fix. @GracellaQSumarlin

Comment: @lemon i alr added the code im working on bc now it gives me all the 0s for temperature and humidity columns

Comment: see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3bd822124f78839cf309e5c87014ae60), but it's (almost) the same answer as @lemon already posted.... 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue of your query is that you're grouping on the "*DateTime*" field, which is equal for every row and does not identify the group you want. What identifies the group is really the combination of the first part of the "*TagName*" field and the "*Datetime*" together.

Since we can't use "*TagName*" directly, we can extract the interesting part (e.g. `'SGHAST_000<n>'` from `'SGHAST_000<n>_<fieldname>'`) using MySQL [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function. When you pass a character (in our case `_`) and an index i (in our case `2`), it will retrieve everything in the string between the first character and the ith character (in our case `'SGHAST_000<n>'`).

Once we are able to build our group, we can use that inside a `GROUP BY` clause, and use MySQL [`MAX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_max) aggregation function to extract the values of temperature and humidity when and only when these occur inside the "*TagName*" field.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(TagName, '_', 2) AS TagName,
       MAX(CASE WHEN TagName LIKE '%Temp'     
                THEN Value END        ) AS Temperature,
       MAX(CASE WHEN TagName LIKE '%HUMIDITY' 
                THEN Value END        ) AS Humidity
FROM testingintern
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(TagName, '_', 2), 
         Datetime
```

You can play with it (and select what specific function returns) at this [link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kv5fTEdKkFELvmsTA65ifP/2).